# What is the difference between two different versions of VLC nightly builds?

Tags: vlc-media-player, version

This will soon be deprecated as far as the specific version numbers are concerned, but the general idea maybe will not:

While the stable build of VLC is at a certain point 2.1.5, there is a [VLC nightly build](http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/win32/?C=M;O=D) that is numbered 2.2 but also a 3.0.0.

What is the difference between these last two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nightlies are a 'courtesy' to testers, to save them having to do their own build from repo every day. The stable releases are the ones on the 'front page' of any organisation's structure, for consumer use.

The build number is the number of commits to the code repository - the number itself can be since the last fork, or since the last major revision number 2.0.0 etc depending on how that particular repo is organised.

For VLC, the latest builds are
vlc-2.2.0-20140913-0202/ 2014-09-13 02:45    [revision 202 of Stable version 2 (or perhaps 2.2, it's hard to tell), 13 sept, 2014]
&
vlc-3.0.0-20140913-0005/ 2014-09-13 01:10  [revision 5 of 'alpha' version 3, 13 sept, 2014]

2.2.0 build 202 will be slight tweaks since the last stable release, small bug fixes etc
3.00 build 5 could be anything - major interface changes, codec updates... you'd have to look at the repo or their published documentation to even guess.

Comment: can you please provide some links to the info documentation for 3.0.0 - as an example? ("the repo or their published documentation") - i'm a bit lost on videolan websites -

Comment: doesn't seem to be any yet - https://wiki.videolan.org/Developers_Corner